# MPMoviePlayerControllerにプレイリストを設定したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

MPMoviePlayerControllerにプレイリストを設定したいのですが、MPMoviePlayerControllerは引数に配列を取るクラスではないとのことで下記のようなコードを書いてみました。
が、やはりエラーが出てしまいます。
どの部分がいけないのでしょうか。
どなたか教えてください、よろしくお願い致します。

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MovieTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"movieCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=emu.mp4"];

    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=penguin.mp4"];

    NSArray *urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url1,url2,nil];




    for (int i=0; i<urls.count; i++)
    {
        urls = urls[i];

        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:urls];

        [moviePlayerController setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];

        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];


       if([self.movieList indexOfObject:moviePlayerController] == NSNotFound ){
        [self.movieList insertObject:moviePlayerController atIndex:indexPath.row];


       }}

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: どのようなエラーがログに出力されるかを記述すると、回答者が答えやすくなるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、ループの中でループカウンタに使用している変数(urls)に代入するのはNGです。

```
for (int i=0; i<urls.count; i++)
{
   urls = urls[i];
}}
```

---- 追記 -----
単純な順番に再生だけなら下記のような感じでいけます（一応、動作確認済み）
ただ、前の動画、次の動画、早送り、巻き戻し等の機能を備えたものにするのは下記では足りません。
「MPMoviePlayer playlist」等で検索すると情報が出てきます。

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* mv_;
    NSArray* uris_;
    NSInteger nextPlayNo_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // プレイリストを作成する
    [self createPlayList];
    // 通知を追加する
    [self addNotification];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)createPlayList
{
    uris_ = @[
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=emu.mp4"]
              , [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=penguin.mp4"]
              , [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ajisaba.net/motion/dnld.php?fpath=emu.mp4"]
              ];
    nextPlayNo_ = 0;
}

- (void)startupMoviePlayer
{
    mv_ = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:uris_[nextPlayNo_]];
    mv_.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    mv_.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    mv_.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    mv_.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    mv_.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    mv_.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [mv_ prepareToPlay];
    [self.view addSubview:mv_.view];
}

#pragma mark - Notifications

- (void)addNotification
{
    // 再生終了時の処理
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playbackNextMovie)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)playbackNextMovie
{
    nextPlayNo_++;
    if ([uris_ count] <= nextPlayNo_) {
        return;
    }
    [mv_ setContentURL:uris_[nextPlayNo_]];
    [mv_ prepareToPlay];
}

#pragma mark - IBAction

- (IBAction)touchupStartup:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self startupMoviePlayer];
}
```

Comment: わざわざお時間を割いて頂きありがとうございます。
movieをTableViewで並べて、cellがタップされると詳細(再生)画面に移る簡単なアプリを作りたいのですがなかなか完成しません..><
追記のコードでも試してみました！ありがとうございました。

Comment: セルをタップしたら再生画面に遷移するのであればプレイリストは不要だと思います（セルとURLを紐付けておいてタップしたセルのURLを設定するとか）。一度気分を変えて作成されているアプリのつくりを整理すると良いかもしれません。あと、TableViewの使い方についても再確認しておくと良いと思います。

Comment: なるほどです。ありがとうございます。助かりました！